# Аутентификация по номеру телефона в Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, python-3.6, vedis

Требуется помощь в реализации авторизации в telegramm bote по номеру телефона.
пример: я заношу номера телефонов в в базу ручками и когда пользователь подключается к боту будет происходить сравнение номера с базой и только после этого пускать в бота.
есть пример c бд vedis и она не сложна в реализации.
https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter11.html
я не могу понять как это реализовать только под номер телефона.
бот будет использоваться в компании как база знаний.
есть небольшая часть кода.

```
# Обрабатывает команду /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def commands_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Приветствую Вас в базе знаний компании . нажмите  /help  чтобы продолжить")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['support'])
def commands_support(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Телефоны")


# страница справки
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def command_help(m):
    cid = m.chat.id
    help_text = "Доступны следующие команды: \n"
    for key in commands:  
        help_text += "/" + key + ": "
        help_text += commands[key] + "\n"
    bot.send_message(cid, help_text)  



# обработчик по умолчанию для любого другого текста
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def command_default(m):
    # это стандартный ответ на обычное сообщение
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Я не понимаю \"" + m.text + "\"\nМожет быть, попробуйте страницу справки на /help")
```

подскажите как это все реализовать в эту часть кода.
буду очень признателен

Answer (score 1):

1. Делаешь хендлер контактов: `content_types=['contact']`
2. В сообщении будет ключ `contact`. Делаешь проверку: `if msg.contact.user_id == msg.from_user.id`
3. Если человек отправил свой номер, то проверка пройдет успешно, если нет, то это номер другого человека
4. Потом в делаешь проверку на наличие `msg.contact.phone_number` в базе данных

Надеюсь помог. Так же можешь заменить
`func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text']` на `content_types=['text']`. Разницы нет